# (Rails) Is there a Koala equivalent for Twitter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, ruby-on-rails-3.1, koala

[Koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) provides a very easy way to post a status update on a user's wall for Facebook. I was wondering if a gem existed to do similar things with Twitter: in other words, I'm looking for a gem that makes it easy to allow your application to tweet something for a user.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Have you searched on github for a twitter gem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is well documented and maintained:

https://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter